# Triangle law of vector addition vs Pythagorean theorem

Tags: vectors

Suppose there is a vector a of magnitude 5 units to the east, another vector b of magnitude 6 units to the north. To find magnitude of vector a + vector b,

By the triangle law of vector addition, it is 5 + 6 units = 11 units.

By Pythagorean theorem, it is sqrt(5^2 + 6^2) = sqrt(61)

Which answer is right? If so, why is the other wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pythagorean theorem answer is the right one. The problem with the other is that it's based on a misunderstanding of the triangle law of vector addition.

The triangle law of vector addition shows you how to add two vectors to get another vector. Its purpose is just to convey that vector addition corresponds to the triangle picture. What you appear to have extrapolated is that this corresponds to adding *magnitudes* (lengths) of vectors, too. **Adding vectors is different from adding lengths.** In the language of vectors, the correct answer to your question is the *magnitude* of the sum of your two vectors. As another poster noted, your two vectors are [5,0] and [0,6], which sum to [5,6]. You are interested in the *magnitude* of the vector [5,6], which is given by the Pythagorean formula $\sqrt{5^2 + 6^2}$, not $5+6$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Here, what does a vector of 11 units mean then?

Comment: @zibzabpuzzless I'm not sure what you mean. It seems like you're just starting to learn this material, and it would probably be helpful for you to either keep studying whatever you're reading to learn this material, or talk about it in person with someone knowledgeable. It's hard to judge just where someone's misunderstandings are in an online question-and-answer like this.